# Image alignment issue in table

Tags: html, css

I can't for the life of me get this image to center in the table I made for an HTML email.  Any suggestions?  I keep seeing online to style my `<td>` with `text-align:center`, but that just isn't working for me.

```html
<body style="padding: 0; background-color:#800000">
  <table align="center" style="background-image:url(../images/intro.png); display:block; max-width:650px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <th>New Video On American Vineyard Website!</th>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/index.html#modal-video14">
          <img src="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/video.play.png"  alt="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg" width="100%" style="background:URL(http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg) center center no-repeat;display:block;">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: remove display block style in table style

Comment: Thanks, that worked great for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables by default are `display:table;`. If you override this property it won't work as a normal table.

```html
<body style="padding: 0; background-color:#800000">
  <table align="center" style="background-image:url(../images/intro.png); max-width:650px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <th>New Video On American Vineyard Website!</th>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center;">
        <a href="http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/index.html#modal-video14">
          <img src="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/video.play.png"  alt="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg" width="100%" style="background:URL(http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg) center center no-repeat;display:block;">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove display:block in table style

```html
<body style="padding: 0; background-color:#800000">
          <table align="center" style="background-image:url(../images/intro.png);  max-width:650px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <th>New Video On American Vineyard Website!</th>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:center;">
                <a href="http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/index.html#modal-video14">
                  <img src="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/video.play.png"  alt="http://americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg" width="100%" style="background:URL(http://www.americanvineyardmagazine.com/images/featvideos/featvideo14.jpg) center center no-repeat;display:block;">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </body>
```

Comment: I remove my answer because it's the same as you. I just point that: « The table is actually displayed as a block element so item into will not be centered with `text-align: center` because this work only on inline/ inline-block/table item. »